# How do I use Django's naturaltime package in a React frontend?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jsx, humanize

I would like to use the Django `naturaltime` functionality from the `humanize` package, or something similar, in my React frontend.

Here is my current code:

```
<p>
     <b>
        {user.username} {post.created_at}
    </b>
</p>
```

Here is what I'm currently getting:

[image]

And here is what I'd like to get:

[image]

I appreciate any help - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `react-moment` package to solve this issue.